# Playing audio in j2me fails

Tags: exception, audio, java-me, midlet

I'm having difficulty playing any audio in my j2me application.

I've tried to play a simple tone, only to receive an exception: "Device Busy, cannot play the tone".

I've tried to play an mp3 file that is embedded in my .jar and ended up getting an exception stating that the media contains Unsupported Data.

Here's the code that I used to try to play a simple tone:

```
try{
    Manager.playTone(ToneControl.C4, 4000, 100);
}catch(Exception e){myForm.append("Exception: " + e.getMessage());}
```

The code that I used to try and play an mp3 file is located here: [Playing Audio with J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473809/playing-audio-with-j2me/479948#479948)

The device I am using is a Motorola i290

Comment: Both issues could be device specific. Please supply what device you are attempting to do this for.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your playTone operation in a separate thread.