# Play mp3 in JME

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, mp3, emulation

I want to know how to play a single mp3 file in my program not from the server, but from the local memory stick files, I want some clear details how to give the path for emulator in pc and how to give path in mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how to play music files is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473809/playing-audio-with-j2me) using MMAPI (Mobile Media API). The trick is to get the input stream for the file. For that you will need to use the File Connection API, as described [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/). The paths will vary, though, you'll have to figure out what's right for you.